# import salesforce database in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, salesforce

I created a Rails app with Heroku and i have to import data from Salesforce.

I followed guides from the Devcenter Heroku to setup the project but i have no idea about how to use my database in rails

`heroku config` command show my variable DATABASE_URL (I added it to my env).

here my database.yml. I set the same in development and production (I know it's bad)

```
defaul: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") {5} %>

production:
<<: *default
adapter: postgresql
database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
username: postgres
password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
host: localhost
```

I can access to my database with psql but only with '$DATABASE_URL' in argument. I can't connect to it with '\c'

`#psql $DATABASE_URL
my_db=> \dt salesforce.*`

And it display tables from salesforce I selected on Heroku connect. I can also add or remove content.

I want to do the same into my app: add or remove something from a HTML form, display content of this db...

I'm a beginner with Salesforce and Rails

**EDIT** for Caffein coder:
My schema.rb. I may modify it by following some tutorials but i'm not sure at all

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160923134925) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "hstore"
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "title"
    t.integer "price"
    t.text    "description
  end
end
```

Comment: You will need controllers and model to handle the salesforce data in rails , can you post the schema.rb file ?

Comment: How to name the controller and the model. I'll edit to add my shema.rb ?

Comment: Tellimi see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well , you need to understand how rails works first . In a seperate application, just run this command to see how it will generate models and controllers for you

```
rails generate scaffold Product title:string price:integer decription:text
```

You won't need the migration file , but you can copy over the controllers, models and views from that application to yours .

Comment: well i understood a bit how it works. 2 questions, some variables are "@product" ans some other are "@products" why ?.
In "psql $database_url" i have the "products" table and nothing about salesforce. I must type "\dt salesforce.*" to see the others tables. why ? i'

Comment: When you have a looping of more then one product to display , then @products is used . When there's just single info needed of a particular product then you can use product . This is in terms of view .